# What is the difference between cuke4duke.Table.rows() and cuke4duke.Table.raw()?

Tags: cucumber

What is the difference between [cuke4duke.Table.rows()](http://cukes.info/cuke4duke/cuke4duke/apidocs/cuke4duke/Table.html#rows%28%29)   and [cuke4duke.Table.raw()](http://cukes.info/cuke4duke/cuke4duke/apidocs/cuke4duke/Table.html#raw%28%29)
?

I've found that when I'm passing a table with one row only, rows() returns a list of size 0;

**Cucumber steps**

```
Then I see the following projects in the ProjectList
| My Private Project |
```

**Java implementation**

```
@Then ("^I see the following projects in the ProjectList$")
public void iSeeTheFollowingProjectsInProjectList(cuke4duke.Table table) {
    table.rows().size(); // gives 0 
    table.raw().size(); // gives 1
```

<strike>But the following does work as intended</strike> It does!

**Cucumber steps**

```
Then I see the following projects in the ProjectList
| Regression Project 3 |
| My Private Project |
```

**Java implementation**

```
@Then ("^I see the following projects in the ProjectList$")
public void iSeeTheFollowingProjectsInProjectList(cuke4duke.Table table) {
    // When I asked, I thought this was returning 2, but it's not, it's returning 1
    table.rows().size();
    table.raw().size(); // gives 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results aren't reproducible in Cucumber-Ruby.
For the first scenario `Table#rows()` returns 0 results and `Table#raw()` - 1 result
For the second scenario `Table#rows()` returns 1 result and `Table#raw()` - 2 results

`Table#rows()` recognizes the first row as table header.

So if your results are true (I haven't checked it), it may be a bug in Cuke4Duke.

But all work on Cuke4Duke is [defunkt](https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/blob/master/README.textile) so it won't get fixed.

Comment: What do you mean it is defunct? Can I get a link?

Comment: @JuanMendes just look at Cuke4Duke's [readme](https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/blob/master/README.textile) and [this issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/issues/131)

Comment: Thanks for the info on cuke4duke, I don't know what that issue means, since they say that Java is still supported. In any case, regarding the answer, it may be that what I reported isn't accurate, there may not be a bug. What you're saying makes a lot of sense, and it's probably what is happening. I'll accept the answer on Monday at work when I can verify it.

Comment: @JuanMendes "they say that Java is still supported". They don't support Cuke4Duke. They support only Cucumber-JVM.

Comment: No bug in Cuke4Duke, and you're absolutely right, sorry about the misleading information in the question